# Changing fonts for the Smuxi application

Tags: fonts, user-interface

I was checking out the graphical IRC client smuxi, which I had never heard of before. This application appears to be a GNOME application.

Anyway, how do I change the default font on this app? The default font is quite tiny, and I would like to make it larger. I'd prefer to make just the font on this app to be enlarged, and not all gnome applications (asuming that is an option).

I'm running a wheezy-backports version of smuxi (0.11~rc5-1~bpo70+1) on Debian wheezy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the default font and font size under Preferences -> Interface -> Output. Check the "Font override" checkbox and then set your font and size in the bar to the right.

[image]

You can change it to whatever you want:

[image]

and make it as big as you want:

[image]